# crop webcam output

Tags: video, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3. I have a USB webcam. I can control various aspects of the webcam output using `v4l2-ctl` e.g.

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl focus_auto=1,white_balance_temperature_auto=1,backlight_compensation=1,brightness=64
```

What I would like to be able to do is crop the webcam output for use in online meetings (it currently shows too much background). But none of the parameters returned by `v4l2-ctl -l` seem to relate to cropping. I also notice that the sliders in the "Cropping & Compose" settings of `qv4l2` don't move, and nothing relating to cropping appears when I run `guvcview`. Is it possible to crop the webcam output?

Here are the details of the webcam from `lsusb`

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2cb4 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Webcam
```

And here are details of the driver from `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -D`

```
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : Webcam: Webcam
    Bus info         : usb-0000:09:00.3-1
    Driver version   : 5.11.22
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out that I can crop the webcam output using another loopback device and `ffmpeg`.  The following zooms in by a factor set in the variable "fac".

```
fac=1.4
ffmpeg -vcodec mjpeg -r 30 -s 1920x1080 \
       -i /dev/video0 \
       -vf "scale=$fac*iw:-1, crop=iw/$fac:ih/$fac","format=yuv420p" \
       -f v4l2  /dev/video10
```

I can then choose the relevant video as input before I join my meeting.